# How do I make a space between words when writing to a text file in python

Tags: python

The following code writes to a text file

```
if classno== '1':
    f = open("class1.txt", "a")
if classno== '2':
    f = open("class2.txt", "a")
if classno== '3':
    f = open("class3.txt", "a")
f.write(name) 
f.write(score)
f.close()
```

However, in the text file the name and score do not have space between them for example, how could I change "James14" in to "James 14"

Comment: f.write(' ') inbetween them is 1 of many ways

Answer (score 13):

You can try

```
f.write(name) 
f.write(' ') 
f.write(score)
```

Or

```
f.write(name + ' ') 
f.write(score)
```

Or

```
f.write(name ) 
f.write(' ' +score)
```

Or

```
f.write("{} {}".format(name,score))
```

Or

```
f.write("%s %s"%(name,score))
```

Or

```
f.write(" ".join([name,score]))
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to write that space:

```
f.write(name) 
f.write(' ') 
f.write(score)
```

or use string formatting:

```
f.write('{} {}'.format(name, score))
```

If you are using Python 3, or used `from __future__ import print_function`, you could also use the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), and have it add the space for you:

```
print(name, score, file=f, end='')
```

I set `end` to an empty string, because otherwise you'll also get a newline character. Of course, you *may* actually *want* that newline character, if you are writing multiple names and scores to the file and each entry needs to be on its own line.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way would be to simply concatenate with a space character

```
f.write(name + ' ' + score)
```

A more robust method (for if the formatting gets more involved) is to use the `format` method

```
f.write('{} {}'.format(name, score))
```

Answer (score 2):

Bhargav and Martjin's answers are good. There are many ways to do it. I'd like to add that the `.format` way seems to be a little better because you can potentially reuse the arguments and organize your code better.

Answer (score 0):

You should format a string.

```
output = "%(Name)s %(Score)s" %{'Name': name, 'Score':score}
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Basically, %(Name)s is a placeholder (denoted by the %) for a string (denoted by the s following the parentheses), which we will reference by "Name". Following our format string, which is wrapped in "", we have this weird thing:

%{'Name': name, 'Score':score}

This is a dictionary that provides replacements for the "Name" and "Score" placeholders.